# how to get click of a spinner and disable/enable it on a certain condition

Tags: android

I have 3 spinners for choosing class, division and subject. These 3 are dependent on each other. I want to enable division's spinner only after selecting a class, and enable subject's spinner after selecting both class and division. and i want to check whether spinners is enable or not when i click on the spinner.

I have done enabling and disabling  spinners by using setEnabled like below:

```
        spDivision.setEnabled(true);
        spDivision.setEnabled(false);
```

And, it is working for me.

I have used onitemSelected listener

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    ClassDivData classDivData = (ClassDivData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    if(parent == spClass)
    {
        clsId = classDivData.getId();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        if(classDivData.getId()>0)
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + classDivData.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(parent == spDivision)
    {
        divId =classDivData.getId();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        if (classDivData.getId()>0)
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + classDivData.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else if(parent == spSubject)
    {
        subId =classDivData.getId();
        // Showing selected spinner item
        if (classDivData.getId()>0)
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + classDivData.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    enablingSpinners(); // to enable or disable spinners
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

function enableSpinners() is used to enable or disable spinners

```
private void enableSpinners() {

    if(clsId >-1)
    {
        spDivision.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        spDivision.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if(clsId >-1 && divId >-1)
    {
        spSubject.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else {

        spSubject.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Note: -1 is the default value of spinners

My problem is i couldn't get the click of the spinner. My need is when i click on the spinner i want to know whether that spinner is enabled or not. Only then i could show the user that he have to select class first for selecting a division.

I have tried setOnClickListener with the spinner.

```
spDivision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!spDivision.isEnabled())
            {
                Toast.makeText(AddHomeWorkActivity.this, "First choose a class", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

But i got error like below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
```

And i tried that too. But got error like below:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setOnItemClickListener cannot be used with a spinner.
```

I have searched a lot for the solution to my problem and so many results. But i didn't get an actual solution to my problem

Comment: `isenabled` is there

Comment: please add more code.

Comment: You need onItemSelectedListener

Comment: @ManojPerumarath my issue is i want to get the click of the spinner then only i could check is enabled

Comment: @netflixspotify have added some more code

Comment: @Zun i have onItemSelectedListener for getting selected item. But that will be needed after selecting data, right? Here i need the click of the spinner. If disabled i couldn't select a value, right?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `setOnItemSelectedListener`,

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

To know whether your spinner is enabled, use

```
if(spinner.isEnabled())
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But i have already used `setOnItemSelectedListener`. My question is where i should use this   `spinner.isEnabled` , I have added some more code to my question. Please go through it